# Mock WebSecurity dependencies when testing controllers in Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, testing, spring-security

To have fast tests for my controller I want to use `@WebMvcTest`. I wrote server-side unit tests for the controller. These are basically simple unit tests involving the sliced Spring application context:

```
@WebMvcTest(DemoController.class)
class DemoControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @WithAnonymousUser
    void shouldNotHaveAccessWhenAnonymous() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "pascal", roles = "USER")
    void shouldHaveAccessWithUserRole() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/hello"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string("Hello"));
    }
}
```

The controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
class DemoController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public String admin() {
        return "Admin";
    }

}
```

But as soon as is start involving more dependencies in my `WebSecurityConfig` like the `MyUserDetailsService` (which itself has a dependency on the `UserObjectRepository`) the problems start to appear.

```
@Autowired
public WebSecurityConfig(final MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService) {
    this.myUserDetailsService = myUserDetailsService;
}
```

When I run the tests Spring cannot load the ApplicationContext (`NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.MyUserDetailsService' available`).

This does make sense when I take a look at the documentation of `@WebMvcTest`. It says that components, services, and repositories will not be auto-configured. But in the last section, it says that Spring Security will be auto-configured when using this annotation. Additional configuration is available using the `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`.

From my point of view there nothing special to do and even though I want to set the `secure` config in `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` it is enabled by default and deprecated. They mention that the `secure` property is deprecated since 2.1.0 in favor of Spring Security's testing support. But I cannot find more details about a dedicated Spring Security testing support regarding this topic (i already use `@WithMockUser` etc. in my tests)

```
 * <p>
 * Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only
 * configuration relevant to MVC tests (i.e. {@code @Controller},
 * {@code @ControllerAdvice}, {@code @JsonComponent},
 * {@code Converter}/{@code GenericConverter}, {@code Filter}, {@code WebMvcConfigurer}
 * and {@code HandlerMethodArgumentResolver} beans but not {@code @Component},
 * {@code @Service} or {@code @Repository} beans).
 * <p>
 * By default, tests annotated with {@code @WebMvcTest} will also auto-configure Spring
 * Security and {@link MockMvc} (include support for HtmlUnit WebClient and Selenium
 * WebDriver). For more fine-grained control of MockMVC the
 * {@link AutoConfigureMockMvc @AutoConfigureMockMvc} annotation can be used.
 * <p>
```

The tests are fine in general. They test the controller methods and their method security configuration. The problems only start to roll in when I add more dependencies and separate classes which I then try to inject in my `WebSecurityConfig`.

How can I mock these dependencies so that my controller tests are working with a sliced context instead of starting the whole application context with `@SpringBootTest`?

Comment: Can you add your controller code? Regardless, you can use the `@MockBean` annotation to mock these dependencies: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html

Comment: Yes, I could mock dependencies of the controller with `@MockBean`, but that is not the case here. I have dependencies in my `WebSecurityConfig`, not in the controller.

Comment: As the documentation I referred to notes, `@MockBean` mocks beans in the 
 spring context, not the controller.

Comment: Are you running your test with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`

Comment: Yep, `@MockBean` does that, but that would mean I have to mock dependencies from the `WebSecurityConfig` in every single test that uses the Security. Which means every Controller in the whole application. That does not make sense to me.

Comment: Yes, `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` is included in the `@WebMvcTest` annotation. Please be aware of, that this setup already uses JUnit 5. The annotation itself is marked with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`. Which is the equivalent in JUnit 5.

Answer (score 0):

So the security config is obviously loaded otherwise you wouldn't have to bother with `@WithMockUser` etc. You can then use Spring's `@MockBean` annotation to mock dependencies in WebSecurityConfig.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html

> Annotation that can be used to add mocks to a Spring
>   ApplicationContext

To avoid repetition in your test classes, you can create an abstract base test class which your controller tests extend:

```
public abstract class BaseControllerTest{

   @MockBean
   private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
}
```

That should be it for this case. For any mocked beans for which you requrie to control the behaviour, you can use standard Mockito functionality.